# MS Access 2010: Unbound combo box won't update

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I've created a form in MS Access 2010 using an unbound combo box to select table entries by names and a popup form to insert new entries to the database. As the combo box does not update on it's own, I've tried forcing an update with `Forms![main_form].[unbound_cmb].Requery` and `Forms![main_form].Form.Refresh`/`Requery` in the popup form "save" button OnClick event but none of the three approaches works.

So how can I update the combo box after adding a new record/clicking the "save" button?

Comment: Not 100% sure about this, but when you open the popup form, the form with the combobox loses focus. Could you add a "Form_GotFocus" event on the main form that requeries the records for the combobox? Or you could have a timer that checks to see if the popup has closed... but you should be able to requery the combobox on close. Hopefully someone will provide a better solution...

Comment: After changing the order of macro commands from `mod_update()` (my VBA function) and closing the popup to close and `mod_update()`, the combo box does update, but selecting the new record does not update the form whilst selecting old entries does

Answer (score 0):

Johannes,

What are you using to populate the combo box? a table or a query?

Also, I'm not sure if you need to requery here. I use the VBA Command.Requery to update cascading combo boxes in the After Update event.

I have a similar database used to register people for examination sites. I have a popup form for data entry, a pop up for new testing sites, and a form that uses two unbound combos to filter a report. Both of my combos are self updating and I accomplished this by using queries.


// EDIT You are going to want to read this*************************

A little more about Command.Requery, Requery is used when you need to run the query again, usually against a different key in your query. While it may seem like it is working sometimes, it is probably only working because either Access is automatically refreshing the query by timer, or because you are causing a refresh by closing the form.  The problem you are having is caused by your query not being refreshed, not because it is not requerying properly.

See my comment below for a simple work around this problem. If, for some reason, you need to always have the form with the combo selection open, then try to have a refresh command on your save button. However, I strongly suggest you follow the method in my comment, as it has been working for me with out any issues.

Comment: I'm using the query `SELECT [main_data].ID, [main_data].name FROM main_data ORDER BY [main_data].name;` to populate the combo box

Comment: I just used the following and it updated the combobox (and as I type this, I see the difference we have -- note the ! versus the . )
    Forms![Form1]![unbound_cmb].Requery
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

Comment: `Forms![Form1]![unbound_cmb].Requery` did not change anything, but `DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name` throws an "invalid use of Me keyword" error

Comment: That's really strange about not liking 'Me.Name'! Gotta ask - you didn't already issue a close command did you? Do you get a compile error? Where is your 'Save' button - in the 'Detail' section? Do you have a subform?

Comment: No, I haven't already issued a close command. The onClick macro just runs `mod_update()`, which contains the Requery and Close command only. The popup form is one single plain form with the button in the detail section.

Comment: Progress -- maybe ... I had my 'Save' button in the popup form header and all wored fine.  Just moved to the Detail section and when the popup is closed, the combobox on the first form is NOT updated to reflect the addition. If I close/reopen the main form, the new record appears.

Comment: Moving the 'Save' button to the header didn't help as well, so I simply removed it, added the `Requery` command to the onClose macro and the ComboBox does requery but selecting the new entry does not update the main form.

Comment: Wayne is right, Sorry I forgot to mention. An easy work around will be for you to add a button to your data entry form that will close it and open your combo selection from, and a button on your combo form that will close the combo form and open up the data entry from. This can easily be accomplished using macros and you might find that it will make you (or your users) more productive as they can easily flow from form to form. The problem seems to be in the fact that you have both forms open at once, if this does not meet your needs, then try the refresh command, instead of requery.